# Is there any way to solve two matrices in SymPy symbolically by comparing them?

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I have two matrices **T** and **T_given**. Both of them are symbolic matrices in SymPy as shown below:

[image: T and T_given]

I want to solve the equation **T = T_given**, that is, **T - T_given = 0** to get the values (albeit symbolic) for

[image: theta1, theta2, theta4, and d3]

I have tried SymPy's solve function but it throws an error saying "Mix of Matrix and Scalar Symbols"

[image: error message]

Comment: I am not that familiar with sympy, but my first step would be seeing if solving 1x1 matrices works. What happens if you make `T_given=[T00]` and `T=[Cos(theta1)]` and then try to solve?

Comment: The error might be coming from `T - T_given` rather than `solve`. It's not possible to answer this question based on the information provided as I don't know how any of the symbols are defined

Comment: Did you find the answer? Now I'm facing the same problem finding inverse kinematics